# how to set google analytic link to my htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, google-analytics

//here is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^glamestates\.co\.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.glamestates.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] # <-- Mind the 'L'!

    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

where about to add this google analytics link in my htaccess

```
glamestates.co.uk/googlec7feca3a4513beef.html
```

what I have got so far but this doesn't work. I added in line five

```
RewriteRule ^glamestates\.co\.uk\googlec7feca3a4513beef\.html$ http://www.glamestates.co.uk\googlec7feca3a4513beef.html%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to paste the googlec7feca3a4513beef.html file into Webroot folder rather than Root

[Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584160/how-to-set-google-analytic-link-to-my-htaccess)